# BEMSimpleLineGraph X-Axis Labels not showing for phones newer than iPhone 5

Tags: graph, bemsimplelinegraph

I've created a line graph using BEMSimpleLineGraph Pod, but, for the life of me, can't figure out why the x-Axis labels aren't showing up on any device newer that an iPhone 5.

EDIT: I should mention enableXAxisLabel = YES by default.

Here is the code to lay out the graph:

```
#import "WeightChartCell.h"

@implementation WeightChartCell

@synthesize viewCell, arrayPlots, myGraph, labelWeightHistory;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    float width = viewCell.bounds.size.width;

    self.myGraph = [[BEMSimpleLineGraphView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-20, 40, width+20, 150.0)];
    self.myGraph.dataSource = self;
    self.myGraph.delegate = self;
    self.myGraph.colorTop = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.myGraph.colorBottom = [UIColor colorWithRed:190/255.0 green:218/255.0 blue:246/255.0 alpha:1];
    self.myGraph.colorLine = [UIColor colorWithRed:124/255.0 green:181/255.0 blue:236/255.0 alpha:1];
    self.myGraph.colorPoint = [UIColor colorWithRed:124/255.0 green:181/255.0 blue:236/255.0 alpha:1];
    self.myGraph.widthLine = 3;
    self.myGraph.sizePoint = 10;
    self.myGraph.alwaysDisplayDots = YES;
    self.myGraph.colorXaxisLabel = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.myGraph.colorBackgroundXaxis = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.myGraph.enableYAxisLabel = YES;
    self.myGraph.colorYaxisLabel = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.myGraph.colorBackgroundYaxis = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.myGraph.enableReferenceYAxisLines = YES;
    self.myGraph.colorReferenceLines = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.myGraph.enableLeftReferenceAxisFrameLine = NO;
    self.myGraph.enablePopUpReport = YES;
    self.myGraph.enableReferenceAxisFrame = YES;

    [viewCell addSubview:self.myGraph];

    labelWeightHistory.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Progress", nil);
    [self sendSubviewToBack:self.myGraph];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfPointsInLineGraph:(BEMSimpleLineGraphView *)graph {
    return [arrayPlots count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfGapsBetweenLabelsOnLineGraph:(BEMSimpleLineGraphView *)graph {
    return 1;
}

- (NSString *)lineGraph:(BEMSimpleLineGraphView *)graph labelOnXAxisForIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSString *dateStr = [[arrayPlots objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"created_at"];
    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

    // Convert date object to desired output format
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d.MMM"];
    dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    return dateStr;
}

- (CGFloat)lineGraph:(BEMSimpleLineGraphView *)graph valueForPointAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSInteger yPoint = [[[arrayPlots objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"weight"] floatValue];
    return yPoint;
}

@end
```

It comes out as expected on an iPhone 5 device and the iPhone 5 simulator:
[image: iPhone 5]

But they don't show up at all on anything newer than iPhone 5. This is for iPhone 5s:
[image: iPhone 5s]

Comment: I am having the same issue. It seems to work fine on iPhone 5 and even the iPhone 6 and 6+ but not the iPhone 5S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see [this issue on github](https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMSimpleLineGraph/issues/206#issuecomment-103318315). It contains a temporary fix while we work on the official fix.

Thanks!